# return a list of generic C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have a singleton class, holding several list of data. I want to have a function to return one of the list based on the requested data type

```
public interface IRentable
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Book : IRentable
{
    private long _id;
    public long Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}

public class DVD : IRentable
{
    private long _id;
    public long Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
}

public class DBReferenceSingleton
{
    private List<Book> _bookList;
    private List<DVD> _dvdList;

    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities<Entity>() where Entity : IRentable
    {
        switch(typeof(Entity).Name)
        {
            case nameof(Book):
                return _bookList;
            case nameof(DVD):
                return _dvdList;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is not working, since a conversion is needed. I wonder if there is any elegant solution (without serialize all elements or implement IConvertible)?

---

Background: I was looking into the implementation of Repository pattern implementation from Microsoft document website and a couple of YouTube videos. Their base class implementations are bounded with DBContext,
[from Microsoft doc]

```
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal SchoolContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
```

[from youtube]

```
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
```

So, this means this base class cannot be used for databases without EntityFramework. I'm trying to remove DBContext in my base class

```
    public class InMemoryRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IRentable

{
    private IEnumerable<TEntity> _entities;

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        if (_entities == null)
        {
            _entities = DBReferenceSingleton.GetInstance.GetEntities<TEntity>();
        }
        return _entities;
    }

    public TEntity Get(long id)
    {
        GetAll();
        if (_entities == null)
        {
            return default(TEntity);
        }
        return _entities.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
    }
```

(I was wrong in my previous code, as I was using "class" instead of "IRentable" as I thought it will be generic for all classes. After implementing the Get(long id) function. I found I have to have a IRentable interface so I made the changes. And the answer from [The Lemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7239875/the-lemon) work perfectly.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Why do you think generics is appropriate here? Why not just have two methods?

Comment: Don't make it hard than it should be.  How would you cast a `Book` to `Entity`?

Comment: Any time you find yourself doing type checks (of a type parameter) inside the implementation of a generic method you should have a little voice in your head saying "this has gone wrong somewhere". The code inside a generic method should be able to work with *any* type parameter compatible with the constraints expressed on the method, *including types not yet written* when the generic method is authored.

Comment: I've just added the detailed background about why I'm trying to use this.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like generics seem the right tool here; not least because `Book` and `DVD` don't have a common base class.

I think you should have two methods:

```
public List<Book> GetBooks() => _bookList;
public List<DVD> GetDvds() => _dvdList;
```

Comment: The caller is a generic Repo class, so I have to use generic here:
    public class InMemoryRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            if (_entities == null)
            {
                _entities = DBReferenceSingleton.GetInstance.GetEntities<TEntity>();
            }
            return _entities;
        }

Comment: Add what you have in your comment to your question as an edit.

Comment: I've just added all details in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a Cast?

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}

public class DVD
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
}

public class DBReferenceSingleton
{
    private List<Book> _bookList;
    private List<DVD> _dvdList;

    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities<Entity>() where Entity : class
    {
        switch(typeof(Entity).Name)
        {
            case nameof(Book):
                return _bookList as List<Entity>;
            case nameof(DVD):
                return _dvdList as List<Entity>;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the "as List< Entity >" will return null if the object is the wrong type, or the object as the type if it's the right type. The A = B as C pattern works for inherited types as well, just remember to check for null returned values for cases where your type isn't as well known as in this situation

A side comment on the usefulness of having a generic method in this case: In this method you're forced to set the type of entity each time explicitly, which means your method is functionally non-generic - so you might as well make two explicit methods.

One case where a generic method like the one you have might be more useful, is if book and dvd both inherited from a base class, and you had some follow up methods that needed to operate off a list of . For example, you might end up wanting to do something like this instead in your code:

```
public class Book : Rentable
{
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}
public class DVD : Rentable
{
    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
}
public class Rentable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string borrowedBy { get; set; }
}
public class DBReferenceSingleton
{
    private List<Book> _bookList;
    private List<DVD> _dvdList;
    public enum RentableType { Book, DVD }
    public IEnumerable<Rentable> GetEntities(RentableType entityType)
    {
        switch (entityType)
        {
            case RentableType.Book:
                return _bookList.ToList<Rentable>();
            case RentableType.DVD:
                return _dvdList.ToList<Rentable>();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException($"Entity {entityType} not supported");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Overengineered. See the answer bellow: Only 2 lines of code. Apply KISS principle.

Comment: @DA - try to avoid using positional language to refer to answers on SO. For starters, there are various sort orders available, for second some (such as score based) depend on the exact history of those answers up until the current moment and so of course subject to change. If you want to refer to another answer, I'd suggest you use the Share option below the question to obtain a *link* to the answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Sure, I will pay more attention next time.

Comment: "as List<Entity>" works great! Thanks! The caller is a generic type from "class", which means it supposed to work for all types, so it's hard to add a retriction like "Rentable".

public class InMemoryRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class